# Delete dropdown dynamically, always delete the last one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to recreate a real problem, so this example may seem strange, but it will certainly solve my problem.

I have a button, which clicks on it, it generates 3 dynamic dropdowns (a variable called $scope.dropdown is fed, with the list of animals that contains the $scope.aAnimals array, there are currently 3 elements, but in the future Can be "n" elements).

My problem: I want to delete the chosen item. But the last one is always deleted. What I can do?

```
<div ng-repeat='item in dropdown track by $index'>
   <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='MyAnimals[$index]'  
  ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals">
     <option value="">Select an animal</option>
  </select>
    <button type="button" ng-click='delete(item)'  class="btn btn-default">
        delete    
    </button>
</div>
<button ng-click='add()' >generate</button>

$scope.obj = {}
$scope.aAnimals=
[
 { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
 { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
 { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
]

$scope.MyAnimals = [];
$scope.add=function(){
$scope.dropdown=[];
for(var i in $scope.aAnimals){
 $scope.dropdown.push({ "animal": $scope.aAnimals[i].animal });
 $scope.MyAnimals[i] = $scope.aAnimals[i]; //El modelo de cada Select
 }
}

$scope.delete=function(item){
 var index = $scope.dropdown.indexOf(item);
 $scope.dropdown.splice(index, 1);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gFyj0YHH1WZQ79lDyizS?p=preview

Comment: Technically behind the scenes, it deletes the correct item but the value of your dropdown retains the first value and it looks like the last item is deleted. I have updated your plunkr to see this behavior.

Comment: You code is working fine, just that the logic for default select `$scope.MyAnimals[i] = $scope.aAnimals[i]` makes it confusing. I wasn't able to load your plunkr, so I created a new one here fixing this issue - $https://plnkr.co/edit/YosI3hspWGe0uODLXBqK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It deletes the correct item but the value of your MyAnimals scope not updating.So you have to delete the item from the MyAnimals scope as well.

```
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var SidController = function($scope){
      $scope.obj = {}
      $scope.aAnimals=
       [
        { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
        { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
        { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
     ]
     $scope.MyAnimals = [];
     $scope.add=function(){
      $scope.dropdown=[];
      for(var i in $scope.aAnimals){
        $scope.dropdown.push({ "animal": $scope.aAnimals[i].animal });
        $scope.MyAnimals[i] = $scope.aAnimals[i]; //El modelo de cada Select
       }
     }

     $scope.delete=function(item){
       var index = $scope.dropdown.indexOf(item);
       $scope.dropdown.splice(index, 1);
       $scope.MyAnimals.splice(index, 1);
     } 
 };
 SidController.$inject = ['$scope'];
 angular.module('app', []).controller('SidController', SidController);

</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller = "SidController">
  <div ng-repeat='item in dropdown track by $index'>
     <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='MyAnimals[$index]'  
        ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals">
        <option value="">Select an animal</option>
     </select>
     <button type="button" ng-click='delete(item)'  class="btn btn-default">
     delete    
     </button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click='add()' >generate</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass `$index` as argument in delete function from HTML.

```
ng-click='delete($index)'
```

Because passing index you don't need to get index in delete function.
After that you need to remove `$scope.dropdown` and `$scope.MyAnimals` because both scope are in `ng-repeat`. if you remove only dropdown than value of dropdonw apply based on MyAnimals scope.
So your delete function like this

```
$scope.delete=function(index){
   $scope.dropdown.splice(index, 1);
   $scope.MyAnimals.splice(index, 1);
}
```